# deformers are red and do not work?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I've placed a sphere in my scene and want to apply a lattice. I have it selected and then select the modifier, but when I do that along with any modifier, the title of the deformer is red and no deformer shows up. What do I need to do to make that work? All the tutorials I'm seeing show it being as simple as what I'm doing.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave

You have to add a 'Lattice' object *as well as* the object to deform (should be in the shift+a menu, 3D viewport), and point to this lattice from the lattice-modifier added to the object you want to deform...

Have a look at this- https://www.dropbox.com/s/4goj0kobrqmjbut/LatticeExample.blend?dl=0

Chose the sphere, and enable the 'lattice' modifier in the viewport (2nd in the top row of buttons in the modifier settings, in the 'spanner' modifiers tab), bingo!...